# Pylint false positive "<class 'RuntimeError'>: wrapped C/C++ object of type QApplication has been deleted"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyqt, pyqt5, pylint

I have been using my coding environment for a while. This issue happens recently after some upgrades of the pylint or VS-code.

My setup is:

**VS-Code + Python 3.7(anaconda) + pylint 2.5.0**

some extensions I'm using with VS-Code are: Anaconda Extension Pack, Qt for Python

Here is the minimum code you need to reproduce this issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
A demo for pylint
"wrapped C/C++ object of type QApplication has been deleted"
false positive
"""
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    """A simple window"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.variable = 1  # This line triggers the alarm.
        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    newWindow = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Obviously, there is no real problem whatsoever. The above code will run just fine.

In the meanwhile, pylint keeps complaining about:

wrapped C/C++ object of type QApplication has been deleted

[image]

Normally I wouldn't bother. However, this error is preventing pylint from iterating.

Does anyone know what's making pylint unhappy?

PS, here is the settings.json for my VS-Code

```
{
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "selection",
    "editor.tabCompletion": "on",
    "files.eol": "\n",
    "telemetry.enableCrashReporter": false,
    "telemetry.enableTelemetry": false,
    "window.autoDetectHighContrast": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "python.dataScience.notebookFileRoot": "${fileDirname}",
    "python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.pycodestyleEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--extension-pkg-whitelist=PyQt5",
        "--generated-members=numpy.*, torch.*, PyQt5.*",
        "--disable=invalid-name, protected-access, E1102"
    ],
    "python.dataScience.sendSelectionToInteractiveWindow": false,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai",
}
```

I just setup a clean virtual machine and did a quick test with different versions of these packages.
It turns out the problem is introduced since pylint 2.5.0.
Pylint 2.4.4 is fine.

Seems more like a bug than a question. Anyway..

I opened a issue on Github, go check out if you guys run into similar issue:
[#3617](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/3617#issue-617522750) 
It probably also related to astroid. I don't really care, I will just stick with 2.4.4 until better solution come out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is indeed a bug of astroid v2.4.0 and it is fixed since astroid v2.4.1 which is paired with Pylint v2.5.2.